# Drools - Load Large number of rules

Tags: drools

In my application I'm loading nearly 10,000 rule to Drools ( Drools 5.5.0.final). But application throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Exception. My jvm args ,

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this. I also used BigMemory ( http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemory) but still getting the same error.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have enough PermGen? When Drools compiles the rules , it creates a fair number of generated classes.

Comment: Viraj:: Can u plz say about the Heap size and permGen you had, to hold 10,000 rules. I am in need of that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a profiler like VisualVM (free and very easy to run) to see how memory over time graph and take a heap snapshot just before it goes OutOfMemory.

Especially that graph can tell you some interesting things (by adding some `Thread.sleep`'s in your code) which could give you and us a clue what's causing it:

- how much memory you consume before starting anything drools (so just having your dataset in memory)
- how much memory having the rules in memory consumes (so the KnowledgeBase)
- how memory evolves onces you start a drools session from that base and insert your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used VisualVM to analyze the problem. Now the part of problem is ok. I found out that PermGen is running out when inserting rules and adding knowledge packages. I fixed that. But now i have problem with with following exception     "Exception in thread "main" "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread"                                      this happens when inserting facts. Do you have any idea how to resolve this ? . Thanks again for the help . :)

Comment: Also one thing, I used Eclipse Juno. Seems like Juno ignore jvm arguments. But when i used Intellij IDEA , it passed specified jvm args.

Comment: AFAIK Drools does not spawn new Threads. Are you sure your code isn't creating `new Thread`s?

Comment: 100% sure. I'm not creating threads. I increased "max user processes " in linux. Now thread problem is ok. I'm using `statefulKnowledgeSession.insert(fact)` to insert facts.

Comment: That doesn't make sense though. *Drools does not create new threads.* Maybe one of your other libs does.

Comment: I'm inserting nearly 11000 facts in a loop.

Comment: Can u plz say about the Heap size and permGen you had, to hold 10,000 rules. I am in need of that...

Comment: Following are my jvm args `-XX:MaxPermSize=1g
-XX:PermSize=1g
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=16
-Xmx1024M
-Xms1024M
-XX:+TieredCompilation`

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you resuse the same 'statefulKnowledgeSession' for triggering process each time. In this case for each `statefulKnowledgeSession.insert(fact)` new facts are inserted but not removing prevous ones. Is that your case please remove/retract previously inserted facts before triggering new processinsatance using:

```
`ksession.retract(factHandle);
```